# DataGridView & ComboBox Event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Using VB.Net, I have a DataGridView with a ComboBox Column. What even do I use for when the user changes a selection in the ComboBox?

Comment: Also consider filling out your profile so that we can call you something besides "unknown." Your profile is here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/198155/unknown-google

Answer (score 2):

you can this event when the combobox  value has been selected ...

```
Private Sub dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
    Try 
        If (Me.dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = CType(Column.Col,Integer)) Then
            Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(e.Control,ComboBox)
            If (Not (comboBox) Is Nothing) Then
                AddHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.ComboBoxIndexChanged
            End If
        End If
        Return
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Utils.ErrMsg(Ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

SelectedValueChanged

Answer (score 0):

.FormatedValue as in Grid.Item.FormatedValue instead of Value

Comment: is this a comment or an answer? If just a comment, consider editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged - then test for the current cell being in your column of concern.